# Render different website based on http header user agent

Tags: url-rewriting, webserver, cloudflare

I have created 2 version of the website, one for desktop and another for mobile. When user point their browser to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), based on the HTTP user agent, I want my server to serve them different website.

I don't want to use responsive design due to the fact my design and page layout as well as content are quite different between desktop and mobile. Furthermore, we may want to play around with search crawler by having another rule to open another plain HTML website.

I wonder can I configure such rule in my web server? or on Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the user's device by checking the `User-Agent` HTTP header for the first-time visitors OR a cookie for returning visitors, then use a Cloudfalre Worker script that would act as a reverse proxy redirecting requests to either desktop or mobile version of the website/app.

```js
import isMobile from "ismobilejs";

export default {
  fetch(req) {
    const device = isMobile(req.headers.get("user-agent"));

    // TODO: Also check cookies (for returning visitors)

    const { pathname, search } = new URL(req.url);
    const targetUrl = device.phone
      ? `https://m.example.com${pathname}${search}`
      : `https://example.com${pathname}${search}`;

    return fetch(targetUrl, req);
  }
};
```

##### References

- https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile — `User-Agent` parser
- https://github.com/kriasoft/cloudflare-starter-kit — Cloudflare Workers Starter Kit